# state not updated inside specified function

Tags: react-native

So i'm trying to change my state like this

```
export default function RegisterScreen({navigation}) {
  const {register, control, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
  const [state, setState] = useState({current_state: 'initial'});

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(state.current_state);
    setState({current_state: 'login_process'});
    console.log(state.current_state);
  });
}
```

inside on submit. but the state is not changing it is stuck on `initial`

then i'm trying to do this

```
   console.log(this.state.current_state);
    this.setState({current_state: 'login_process'}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.current_state);
    });
```

but i get this error

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is
> not an object (evaluating '_this.state.current_state')

how can i fix it ? and is it the proper way to do state management in react native ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do async actions with useState hook. If you want to trigger changes, try something like this:

```
export default function RegisterScreen({navigation}) {
  const {register, control, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
  const [state, setState] = useState({current_state: 'initial'});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`state.current_state has been changed to: ${state.current_state}`)
  }, [state.current_state])

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(state.current_state);
    setState({current_state: 'login_process'});
    console.log(state.current_state);
  });
}
```

The error you are receiving is that you can't use `this` in functional components.

You can go further with your `useEffect` hook and do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(state.current_state === 'login_process') {
    // add some logic that should happen when login is processing
  }
}, [state.current_state])
```

Comment: it is working thanks, to you. But i have extra question , why i can't get the value of `state.current_state` directly ? I want to do this, if state is loading i want to disable button , did i make wrong approach ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in the code but in not putting
e.preventDefault()

try the following:

```
     const onSubmit = (e,data) => {
        e.preventDefault()
      console.log(state.current_state);
      setState({current_state: 'login_process'});
      console.log(state.current_state);
    });
  }
```